# Rotating text jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this text:

```
<td height="112" align="left" valign="top"><p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf <br />
                                    </p>
                                </td>
```

How can I make it rotate every xxx seconds with jquery?

I'm using this script for rotating an image, and would like to make them rotate together.

http://pastebin.com/bdfYN6nd

Comment: More detail: rotate as in switch. i.e. Show Picture 1 and <td1> for 10 seconds, then Show picture 2 and <td2> for 10 seconds, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use setInterval() to time my image sliders. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval

```
function rotate() {
  /* Image and text rotator code */
}

var intervalID = setInterval(rotate,10000);
```

Then, should you want to stop the rotator, use `clearInterval()`:

```
clearInterval(intervalID);
```